# I just need a SignUp Policy. Anyone know the PolicyId's for ASP.NET Core Azure AD B2C Configurations

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

All I'm looking for is a direct link to the Register User flow for Azure AD B2C.  Currently a user needs to hit the Sign In form, then needs to select "Sign up Now".

I've search high and low through the Azure B2C doco, and can't find the right text for the PolicyId to link to my SignUp page only.

While the doco clearly shows what you need to do with SignUpSignInPolicyId, ResetPasswordPolicyId and EditProfilePolicyId eg...

```
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignInRegister",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEdit",
```

The doco doesn't list the full range of ...PolicyId's, that  `.AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));` allow's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the properties of MicrosoftIdentityOptions in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentityoptions.editprofilepolicyid?view=azure-dotnet-preview). `SignUpSignInPolicyId`, `ResetPasswordPolicyId` and `EditProfilePolicyId` are the
all properties about PolicyId.

[image]

You need to [create user flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows) about sign up and sign in when you want to use SignUpSignInPolicyId. It is similar to other policies. You could try this by following the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C#step-2-modified-the-generated-code).

Comment: The provided link doesn't list the *values* that are valid for any of these properties. It may have at one time but, if it did, it no longer does.

Comment: @MikeHofer Please check the new one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentityoptions?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: The new article is just like the old one. It lists all the available *properties*, but doesn't provide the complete list of acceptable *values* for those properties. For example, "WaveAMagicWand" is not an acceptable SignUpSignInPolicyId. So what are all the available policy ID values?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only `EditProfilePolicyId`, `SignUpSignInPolicyId` and `ResetPasswordPolicyId` are supported by [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web), as can be seen [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/MicrosoftIdentityOptions.cs).

I have raised a [pull request](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/pull/854) for this feature. Hopefully we can get this added soon and we can all have separate 'Sign Up' and 'Sign In' buttons on our web apps!

Comment: It would be a good practice to include any documentation regarding the available features over and above the link to the actual code repo